# Customizing a <b-form-textarea> with label and invalid message

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vuelidate

After having read the BootstrapVue documentation for the ["form textarea" component](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-textarea) am I right that `<b-form-textarea>` does not support the following attributes to be set?

- `invalidFeedback` (as opposed to e.g. `<b-form-input>`)
- `label`

If this is correct is there any easy way to add these attributes?

The following pug template shows the textarea but not the label or the invalid message.

```
b-form-textarea#message(
        v-model="form.message"
        :label="Your message"
        :state="!$v.form.message.$invalid"
        :invalidFeedback="Please enter a message."
        :placeholder="$t('messagePlaceholder')"
      )
```

Comment: First can you tell me where you see the invalidFeedback property. I can't find it in the docs for b-form-input.

The label you have define it yourself like: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-textarea/#auto-height

For feedback you can use the aria-invalid-attribute: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-textarea/#aria-invalid-attribute

Comment: wrap `<b-form-textarea>` in a `<b-form-group>` (which has the invalid/valid feedback).  Be sure to make sure the `state` prop on the input is referencing the same state as the `state` prop on the form group